# How to normalize the size of a tensorflow variable

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing a tensorflow code where I want to normalize the variable vector after each update. The following code works well:

```
 sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
 y = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2], -0.5, 0.5))
 init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
 sess.run(init)

 a = [2, 3]

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a - y))
y = y / tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y)))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

for step in range(100):
  sess.run(train)
  temp2= sess.run(y)
  print(temp2)
```

and gives the desired answer which is [ 0.55469805  0.83205169], a normalized vector in the direction of [2,3]

However, if I change

```
  y = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2], -0.5, 0.5))
```

to

```
  y = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,2], -0.5, 0.5))
```

and

```
  y = y / tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y)))
```

to

```
  y[0] = y[0] / tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y[0])))
```

Then I get the error which says "'Variable' object does not support item assignment". I also changed the loss function to

```
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a - y[0]))
```

Can anybody help how I can normalize a vector column like y[0] of variable type in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `y` is a tensor object , you cannot assign the value to the tensor as you do. Hence, you should works on the array of the tensor, and after that assign the value into like the following:

```
 yArray = y.eval()
 a = [2, 3]

 loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a - y.eval()[0][:]))
 yArray[0][:] = yArray[0][:] / tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(yArray[0][:]))).eval()
 y.assign(yArray)
```

In the above, get the array of the tensor using `eval` function. Then, compute the loss function, and `yArray` normalization. Finally, assign the value of the `yArray` into the `y`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have to try this out. I will leave another comment if it works.

Comment: @SukhoLee If it works, there is no need to leave a comment. Just accept the solution as answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code gives a "No gradients provided for any variable"
error. I think this is because y.eval()[0][:] is a value and not a variable.When I use y[0] instead of y.eval()[0][:], the answer is
[ 1.99994683  2.99990678] which is the unnormalized minimization answer to the loss function.
function.

Comment: @SukhoLee I've run this code in python 3.5. It works fine for me!